# Snakemake running Subworkflow but not the Rest of my workflow (goes directly to rule All)

Tags: snakemake

I'm a newbie in Snakemake and on StackOverflow. Don't hesitate to tell me if something is unclear or if you want any other detail.
I have written a workflow permitting to convert .BCL Illumina Base Calls files to demultiplexed .FASTQ files and to generate QC report (FastQC files). This workflow is composed of :

- **Subworkflow "convert_bcl_to_fastq"** It creates FASTQ files in a directory named Fastq from BCL files. It must be executed before the main workflow, this is why I have chosen to use a subworkflow since my second rule depends on the generation of these FASTQ files which I don't know the names in advance. A fake file "convert_bcl_to_fastq.done" is created as an output in order to know when this subworkflow ran as espected.
- **Rule "generate_fastqc"** It takes the FASTQ files generated thanks to the subworkflow and creates FASTQC files in a directory named FastQC.

---

## Problem

When I try to run my workflow, I don't have any error but **my workflow does not behave as expected**. I only get the **Subworkflow to be ran** and then, the main workflow but **only the Rule "all" is executed**. My **Rule "generate_fastqc" is not executed at all**. I would like to know where I could possibly have been wrong ?
Here is what I get :

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Executing subworkflow convert_bcl_to_fastq.
Building DAG of jobs...
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       convert_bcl_to_fastq
        1
[...]
Processing completed with 0 errors and 1 warnings.
Touching output file convert_bcl_to_fastq.done.
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
Complete log: /path/to/my/working/directory/conversion/.snakemake/log/2020-03-12T171952.799414.snakemake.log
Executing main workflow.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 40
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        1

localrule all:
    input: /path/to/my/working/directory/conversion/convert_bcl_to_fastq.done
    jobid: 0

Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

And when all of my FASTQ files are generated, **if I run again my workflow**, this time it will **execute the Rule "generate_fastqc"**.

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Executing subworkflow convert_bcl_to_fastq.
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done.
Complete log: /path/to/my/working/directory/conversion/.snakemake/log/2020-03-12T174337.605716.snakemake.log
Executing main workflow.
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 40
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       all
        95      generate_fastqc
        96
```

I wanted my workflow to execute itself entirely by running rule "generate_fastqc" just after the completion of the subworkflow execution but **I am actually forced to execute my workflow 2 times**. I thought that this workflow would work since all the files needed in the second part of the workflow will be generated thanks to the subworkflow... **Do you have any idea of where I could have been wrong ?**

---

## My Code

Here is my Snakefile for the main workflow :

```
subworkflow convert_bcl_to_fastq:
    workdir: WDIR + "conversion/"
    snakefile: WDIR + "conversion/Snakefile"

SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards(FASTQ_DIR + "{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:
        convert_bcl_to_fastq("convert_bcl_to_fastq.done"),
        expand(FASTQC_DIR + "{sample}_R1_001_fastqc.html", sample=SAMPLES),
        expand(FASTQC_DIR + "{sample}_R2_001_fastqc.html", sample=SAMPLES)

rule generate_fastqc:
    output:
        FASTQC_DIR + "{sample}_R1_001_fastqc.html",
        FASTQC_DIR + "{sample}_R2_001_fastqc.html",
        temp(FASTQC_DIR + "{sample}_R1_001_fastqc.zip"),
        temp(FASTQC_DIR + "{sample}_R2_001_fastqc.zip")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p "+ FASTQC_DIR +" | " #Creates a FastQC directory if it is missing
        "fastqc --outdir "+ FASTQC_DIR +" "+ FASTQ_DIR +"{wildcards.sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz "+ FASTQ_DIR + " {wildcards.sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz &" #Generates FASTQC files for each sample at a time
```

Here is my Snakefile for the subworkflow "convert_bcl_to_fastq" :

```
rule all:
    input:
        "convert_bcl_to_fastq.done"

rule convert_bcl_to_fastq:
    output:
        touch("convert_bcl_to_fastq.done")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p "+ FASTQ_DIR +" | " #Creates a Fastq directory if it is missing
        "bcl2fastq --no-lane-splitting --runfolder-dir "+ INPUT_DIR +" --output-dir "+ FASTQ_DIR #Demultiplexes and Converts BCL files to FASTQ files
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You need to bind subworkflow to the rule `generate_fastqc`. This may be done by adding `input: convert_bcl_to_fastq("convert_bcl_to_fastq.done")` to rule `generate_fastqc`. I am not sure why snakemake doesn't spit error after the first run. 
PS - Your snakefiles can use some cleanup. For example, specify fastqs as `input` to `generate_fastqc`.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy Thank you for your answer. I've added `convert_bcl_to_fastq("convert_bcl_to_fastq.done")` as an input file to `generate_fastqc` and the fastq files also but it did not change anything, it is still running the subworkflow `convert_to_bcl` and the rule `all`. Here is my new input for `generate_fastqc` : 
`input:
        convert_bcl_to_fastq("convert_bcl_to_fastq.done"),
        R1 = "FASTQ_DIR" + "{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2 = "FASTQ_DIR" + "{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz"`

My new fastqc shell line has `{input.R1}` and `{input.R2}` instead of `{wildcards.sample}`.

Comment: If I try to **add a fake file as an output** for my rule `generate_fastqc` with `output: touch("generate_fastqc.done")` and in rule all 'input: `"generate_fastqc.done`, I get a strange **syntax error related to wildcards** : `SyntaxError:
Not all output, log and benchmark files of rule generate_fastqc contain the same wildcards. This is crucial though, in order to avoid that two or more jobs write to the same file.
  File "/scratch/test_sro/snakemake-tutorial/Snakefile", line 44, in <module>` 
I am going to try to put my rule `generate_fastqc` in another subworkflow and see how it goes...

Comment: I would recommend creating a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it would be easier for people to nail down the issue. It would also allow us to try out the code with minimal setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html) about `subworkflow`s currently states:

```
When executing, snakemake first tries to create (or update, if necessary) 
"test.txt" (and all other possibly mentioned dependencies) by executing the subworkflow. 
Then the current workflow is executed.
```

In your case, the only dependency declared is "convert_bcl_to_fastq.done", which Snakemake happily produces the first time.

Snakemake usually does a one-pass parsing, and the main workflow has not been told to look for sample-files from the subworkflow. Since sample-files do not exist yet during the first execution, the main workflow gets no match in the `expand()` statements. No match, no work to be done :-)

When you run the main workflow the second time, it finds sample-matches in the `expand()` of `rule all:` and produces them.

Side note 1: Be happy to have noticed this. Using your code, if you actually had done changes that mandated re-run of the subworkflow, Snakemake would find an old "convert_bcl_to_fastq.done" and not re-execute the subworkflow.

Side note 2: If you want to make Snakemake be less 'one-pass' it has a rule-keyword `checkpoint` that can be used to re-evaluate what needs to be done as consequences of rule-execution. In your case, the checkpoint would have been `rule convert_bcl_to_fastq` . That would mandate the rules to be in the same logical snakefile (with `include` permitting multiple files though)